# Pre-plagues hail?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, history, plagues-makkos, va-eira

In [Shemot 9:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.9.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it says about the plague of hail:

> "וַיְהִי בָרָד וְאֵשׁ מִתְלַקַּחַת בְּתוֹךְ הַבָּרָד כָּבֵד מְאֹד **אֲשֶׁר לֹא הָיָה כָמֹהוּ בְּכָל אֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם מֵאָז הָיְתָה לְגוֹי**."
>
> "The hail was very heavy—fire flashing in the midst of the hail—**such as had not fallen on the land of Egypt since it had become a nation**."

It sounds like the Torah is saying that prior to Egypt having become a nation, there was a time when fiery hail rained down on the land (otherwise, why mention that the hail had not fallen so since that time?). Are there any sources that discuss this ancient event?

Comment: Ramban disagrees with your diyuk ולא יתכן לומר שהיה כן טרם הוסד העולם, או טרם היות הארץ לגוי https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.9.18.1?lang=he

Comment: @JoelK Thanks, good to know. Though I didn't understand *why* he says such an interpretation is not possible?

Comment: It seems to me like saying "there hasn't been hail like that in recorded history" implies that before that there must have been hail like that.

Comment: The Otzar Midrashim understands it simply asthere never was....but there will be in the future - https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.9.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Otzar%20Midrashim&lang2=bi

Comment: @Dov Had the verse stuck to אשר לא היה כמוהו, I would have thought nothing of it, and such a midrashic interpretation would have made sense. But as it added מאז היתה לגוי...well, it's uncharacteristic phrasing.

Comment: Yes I def hear your point!